# Why does "CanvasRenderingContext2D.rotate()" rotate clockwise

Tags: javascript

When I've worked with Cartesian planes in the past the direction of rotation has always been counterclockwise. Is there a reason that .rotate() is in a clockwise direction?

Comment: Usually in algebra it's like East is 0°, North is 90°, West is 180° and South is 270°.

Comment: The Y axis is also upside down compared to everyday calculus. The rotation in the other direction makes sense, then.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Non-standard_orientation_of_the_coordinate_system it's not specific to canvas2d, same for almost every computer graphics API, same for css, same for SVG etc.

Comment: Great thanks everyone! :D
Not an issue or anything I was just curious!